# problem to use srtcat() to add string to string

Tags: c, buffer, strcat

~~ z_goggamal-input.txt ~~

Make me a sandwich.

What? Make it yourself.

Sudo make me a sandwich.

Okay.

this is the original text file.  i need to change this file

~~like this ~~
Make me a sosandwich.

Whatot? Make itot yourorsoself.

SoSudo make me a sosandwich.

Okay.

it means consonants are changed to '<consonant> o <consonant>', only required to transform 3 **consonants,** specifically R, S and T (both lower case, and upper case).

so i add the transform_char() on the given code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define D_BUFSIZE 4096
#define NUM_ARGS_3 3
#define NUM_ARGS_4 4

#define ERROR_ARGS 1
#define ERROR_OPEN_R 2
#define ERROR_OPEN_W 3
#define ERROR_WRITE 4
#define ERROR_CALLOC 5
#define SUCCESS 0
#define ERROR -1

int BUFSIZE = D_BUFSIZE;

// Function to transform a character to Goggamal language
char transform_char(char c) {
        if (c == 'r'){
        char or[10] = "or";
        char plusr[10] = "r";
        strcat (plusr,or);
        return *plusr;
    }
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *prog_name = strdup(argv[0]);
    int input_fd, output_fd;
    ssize_t return_num_bytes_write, return_num_bytes_read;
    char *buffer;
    char *fn = strdup("makegoggamalA");

    if (argc != NUM_ARGS_3 && argc != NUM_ARGS_4) {
        printf("%s: usage: makegoggamalA source_file target_file [BUFSIZE]\n", prog_name);
        return ERROR_ARGS;
    }

    if (argc == NUM_ARGS_4) {
        BUFSIZE = atoi(argv[3]);
    }

    if (argc == NUM_ARGS_3) {
        BUFSIZE = 1;
    }

    buffer = (char *) calloc(BUFSIZE, sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("calloc");
        return ERROR_CALLOC;
    }

    input_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (input_fd == ERROR) {
        perror("open");
        return ERROR_OPEN_R;
    }

    output_fd = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (output_fd == ERROR) {
        perror("open");
        return ERROR_OPEN_W;
    }

    int total_read = 0;
    int total_write = 0;

    while ((return_num_bytes_read = read(input_fd, buffer, BUFSIZE)) > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < return_num_bytes_read; i++) {
            buffer[i] = transform_char(buffer[i]);
        }
        return_num_bytes_write = write(output_fd, buffer, (ssize_t) return_num_bytes_read);
        if (return_num_bytes_read != return_num_bytes_write) {
            perror("write");
            return ERROR_WRITE;
        }
        total_read += return_num_bytes_read;
        total_write += return_num_bytes_write;
    }

    close(input_fd);
    close(output_fd);
    free(buffer);
    free(prog_name);
    printf("read %'d bytes and wrote %'d bytes done...\n", total_read, total_write);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I just did 'r' character only so far.

I thought i could use strcat function to put "or" after "r"

but when i check the txt file after compiling, there was no error but nothing changed.

output is just the same as original file.

what should i do to edit the code to make <consonant> o <consonant> ?

or is there any other way that I can use instead srtcat function?

Comment: Please look more carefully at `transform_char`. The concatenation makes no sense, because you only return the first `char` of `plusr[10]`. Even if something more was hoped, the concatenation of local variables which could have been defined as a single variable is nonsense. Watch the compiler warnings too, because not all control paths return a value. Were you hoping that the function will return a Goggamal string? That won't work anyway, because you cannot return a local string: it goes out of life.

Comment: Lots going on here, but here's a hint: your output buffer needs to be three times as large as your input buffer, if a single character can be converted into three characters.

Answer (score 1):

"*or is there any other way that I can use instead strcat function?*"
Yes there is another way...

The code below performs the operation you describe. For simplicity, the original text is *hard coded* instead of being read from a file. (Replace this with `fgetc()` to read in one character at a time.) The output is being printed to `stdout`. (Replace these with `fprintf()`.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    char *src =
        "Make me a sandwich.\n"
        "What? Make it yourself.\n"
        "Sudo make me a sandwich.\n"
        "Okay.\n";

    for( ; *src; src++ )
        switch( *src ) {
            case 'r':
            case 'R':
            case 's':
            case 'S':
            case 't':
            case 'T':
                putchar( *src );
                putchar( 'o' );
            /* FALLTHROUGH */
            default:
                putchar( *src );
                break;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Adding counters of source characters and output characters then follows.

```
Make me a sosandwich.
Whatot? Make itot yourorsoself.
SoSudo make me a sosandwich.
Okay.
```

**EDIT** Noticed that OP example reuses the same case for both 'ends' of the target character being expanded. Makes code even simpler...